# How to generate a unique div id for django objects displayed in template

Tags: javascript, python, django, html

I am working on a Django project. I have a template which displays all the available posts. Users can like a post. Everything is working fine. But I am facing a problem. Since I am using ajax to change the status of the like button when a user clicks on it, I noticed that all the like buttons of the displayed posts object are affected, when a user clicks on the like button of one of the displayed posts. I want changes to occur just on the like button the user has clicked. Not all the like buttons of the displayed post object

Example of my HTML template looks something of this sort.

```
{% for post in allpost %} <!--for loop to get all post objects in data base-->
{{post.tittle}}
{{post.content}}
{{post.type}}

<!-- like button  for users to be able to like post they fine interesting-->
<a  href="" data-href="{% url 'post:api_like' slug=post.slug %}">
<button id="like">like</button></a>
{% endfor %}
```

So you can see my like button id is not dynamic, which is one of the reasons I am facing this problem. How can I go about generating a dynamic button id for each like button in the for loop post?

Please Help me out

Comment: You can suffix use `post` id, this will make id unique and to attach event handler using CSS class to target them

Comment: so should i do  something like this  <button id="{{post.id}}">like</button> please explain with code example.

Comment: Do you have idea on how i can get this dynamic created id in jquery ?

Comment: Create element like `<button type="button" class="like" id="{{post.id}}">like</button>`  then attach event handler `$(function (){ $('.like').on('click', function(){ var id = this.id; }); }); `

Comment: @Satpal, You should put that in as an answer.

Comment: @john Were you able to get unique id for auto-generated fields? I am stuck in a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers in HTML must be **unique**  instead assign a CSS class and then use it to attach event handlers.

Instead of using *id* attribute, I would recommend to use custom [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) if you want to persists arbitrary data which can be fetched using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```
{% for post in allpost %} <!--for loop to get all post objects in data base-->

    <!-- like button  for users to be able to like post they fine interesting-->
    <button type="button" class="like" data-id="{{post.id}}">like</button>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is a jQuery *Script* to attach event handler and get data on `click` event

```
$(function (){ 
    $('.like').on('click', function(){ 
        //Fetch Id 
        var id = $(this).data('id');                
    }); 
});
```

Comment: in the template is a list of objects generated for post, and each of these objects will have like  button. How can i use the dynamic id generated for each post like button  in jquery to change button color when user clicks on it .   I want just the like button the user has clicked to change color . Help me please . I would like something similar to  instagram or facebook when the user clicks on the like button , just the like button of that post is affected .

Comment: @john use current Element context `this`  in event handlers. `$(this).addClass('your class)`

Comment: It does not work . I am trying to avoid changing the color of all the like buttons on display posts, when user clicks on the like  button  of one of the post . How can i make the like buttons for each post  generate a unique div id . So as  my jquery code can affect just that like button the user has clicked on that post . Not all the like buttons . Please help me . Like i said , it is something similar to instagram like button . Just the like button of the post is affected when user clicks on it .

Comment: @john see https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/t5jvgmd4/2/, Try play with it

Comment: This answer is wrong. Suppose the loop has generated 5 buttons. Then all 5 buttons will have the same class of "like". On clicking any one button jQuery will consider it for all 5 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I came across exactly the same question.  Some answers here are fine when the element is shown only once on the page.  I had a use case where the same HTML content had to be displayed several times on the page *and* I needed a unique id for each (example: a collection of items in a column, a drag and drop mechanism, items are dragged & copied into a second column).  And I obvioulsy needed a distinct id for each.

So I ended up with another solution:

- at the top of your class hierarchy, you can add a method to create a globally unique identifier from any object:

```
class WhateverMyTopClassIs:

    def fresh_uuid(self):
        # returns a fresh uuid4 for each call.  Used by templates to segregate
        # multiple occurrences of the same object
        return str(uuid.uuid4())
```

Then, within template,

- use it once with `{{ my_object.fresh_uuid }}`, or
- if you need to reference it several times, then wrap your template code with a `with` statement like this:

```
{% with the_id=my_object.fresh_uuid %}
   # do stuff
{% endwith %}
```

Hope this helps.